# How do you find the FQDN of the local host?

Tags: go, fqdn

How do you find the FQDN of the local host in Go?

BTW: net.LookupAddr() doesn't work on Windows.  So that's not an option.

Comment: Nope.  That will not return the DNS suffix.

Comment: How would you get the information from the OS? There's nothing specific to Go in this sense. Is the 'USERDNSDOMAIN' environment variable set?

Comment: That will not work.  It is not commonly set.

Where to retrieve the connection DNS suffix depends on the OS.   There are api calls or an /etc file.  I found that Go does not provide a common way across OSs to get it and you will have to write the function yourself for each OS.

For Window I need to call the `IpAdapterAddresses` system call; on linux I will have to figure it out when I port the app to CentOS.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. IIRC `USERDNSDOMAIN` is set when the host is logged into an AD domain, which might not be there, but is it what you really want if it is? Go has no way of knowing what else you might want besides what's configured in the kernel. On linux do you want a PTR record for the first network interface, or do you want the hostname plus a "domain" entry from `resolv.conf`, or do you want the first fqdn listed in `/etc/hosts` for a local address, or do you want to use `nswitch.conf` to lookup the host from some other directory?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The computer often does not know its own FQDN or may not have any way to access the information. There are so many ways for this to fail.

Answer (score 4):

By default there is no short way.

[os.Hostname()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Hostname) doesn't provide the Fully Qualified Domain Name by default.

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/hostname", "-f")
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf(err)
}
fqdn := out.String()
fqdn = fqdn[:len(fqdn)-1] // removing EOL
```

---

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, function `os.Hostname()` returns the system host name reported by kernel. So, if your computer is named `computer1`, `os.Hostname()` returns `computer1`. If your computer is named `computer1.my.office`, `os.Hostname()` returns `computer1.my.office`. On Windows, is the same. If you want the domain name (as referred to the Active Directory domain) you have four ways:

1. Parse the result of this command: `wmic computersystem get domain`
2. Parse the result of this command: `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Domain"`
3. Assume the existence of the environment variable `USERDNSDOMAIN` and evaluate his value (note that: the value of this variable is referred at the domain which user is stored)
4. Check if one of the ip's assigned to the workstation can be resolved via DNS (for this point, you can view this: https://github.com/Showmax/go-fqdn)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform some gymnastics using the net lib as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/ShowMax/go-fqdn/blob/master/fqdn.go).